# failed to import tensorflow.compat.v1

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to run my code which requires tensorflow and [deepxde](https://deepxde.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html). I am running python 3.10.12. I read some document which suggested running on python 3.6, but them my Mac OS M1 fails to install numpy and other dependencies.

```
(base) anshumansinha@lawn-143-215-62-80 deepOscillations % Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/git_project/deepOscillations/./main.py", line 362, in <module>
    NN_MSEs_test = DeepONet(samples, split, points, approx_points, y/np.max(np.abs(y)) , I, inds, neurons, epochs, b_layers)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/git_project/deepOscillations/./main.py", line 272, in DeepONet
    import deepxde as dde
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/backend/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    load_backend(get_preferred_backend())
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/backend/__init__.py", line 110, in get_preferred_backend
    verify_backend(backend_name)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/backend/utils.py", line 78, in verify_backend
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Backend is set as tensorflow.compat.v1, but 'tensorflow.compat.v1' failed to import.
```